# check if user exists: inserts to database without checking?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a login/register system, and I simply cannot figure out why the username entered won't check if there is an existing one in the database.

The email code checks perfectly if there is an existing email but the username goes through even if there is an existing one!

Here is the username code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=:username");
$query->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$count = $query->execute(array(":username" => strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['username']))));
if ($query->rowCount() == 1)
{
    $errors[] = "Time to be original! That user already exists!";
}
```

Here is the WORKING email code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=:email");
$count = $query->execute(array(":email" => strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['email']))));
if ($query->rowCount() == 1)
{
    $errors[] = "Please pick a new email! That email is taken!";
}
```

Comment: Why on Earth are you applying `strip_tags(addslashes())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to call `$query->bindParam` at all.
2. I don't think, that it's necessary to call `strip_tags` and `addslashes`. PDO will quote all the necessary symbols itself.

Try this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=:username");
$count = $query->execute(array(":username" => $_POST['username']));
```

Comment: this does not fix the problem, could you please explain those lines to me? I'm not sure i get them. I get your fixes but could you explain what the SELECT FROM WHERE :username and array(":username" => $POST['username'])

Comment: @user3078911 This means: take value from $_POST array, and put it instead of :username parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `bindParam()` with an positional index (for an anonymous placeholder), then passing the parameter array to `execute()`.  Choose one approach or the other (and, if using named placeholders, don't use positional indexes).